# Aurelia dialog & Typescript async await - Cannot find name 'await'

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, async-await, aurelia

I'm having problems using async await together with [Aurelia Dialog](https://github.com/aurelia/dialog). Basically I want to send away a request when the dialog is closed and currently it gives me syntax error:

> Cannot find name 'await'

If I move the request outside the .WhenClosed function I dont get any syntax error and I can fire away a request.

[image: Cannot find name 'await']

## Why is it that I can't use async await inside the .whenClosed dialog and how can I overcome this?

Comment: *Why is it that I can't use async await* - because you're not using it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The arrow function you pass to to `whenClosed` has to be async

```
async response => {}
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you, i'll accept your answer in 4 mins!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should try to use

```
.whenClose(async (response) => { let result_2 = await this.organisationService... })
```

to instead~